# gsdll32.dll error c# while reading qr code

Tags: c#, pdf, dll, ghostscript

**I am receiving this error while reading qr code from a pdf file :**

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ApplicationException' occurred in PdfToImage.dll
>   Additional information: The gsdll32.dll you provide is not compatible with the current architecture that is 64bit,Please download any version above version 8.64 from the original website in the 64bit or x64 or AMD64 version!

I am trying to read qr with a project from CodeProject. Here is the project link : [Scan and Read QR Code From PDF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/99362/Scan-and-Read-the-Barcode-from-PDF-File)

I tried replace gsdll32.dll with older version but it didn't work.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I don't understand error message says _"...Please download any version above version 8.64 from the original website in the 64bit or x64 or AMD64 version!..."_ but you _"...tried replace gsdll32.dll with older version..."_

Comment: By downloading the 64bit version of the dll.

Comment: I downloaded newer version and replaced it with older version. I mean delete older version on my computer and placed the new version in System32 and SysWOW64 Folders. But I'm still receiving same error message.

Comment: Its pretty unlikely that an **older** version would help. Its not really possible to help you without further information; in particular the PDF file you are using, and the arguments being passed to Ghostscript.

Comment: Looks to me like you need to alter the project settings so that it picks up the correct DLL. You can't use gsdll32.dll with a 64-bit project because (surprise!) gsdll32.dll is a **32**-bit library. You either need to use the 64-bit DLL or alter the code to be 32-bit